# How do I adjust the screen contrast?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, aspire

I am using an Acer Aspire 3680 with Intel GMA 950 video running Ubuntu 16 and I cannot find the command to adjust the screen contrast setting. Too many colors and grays are washed out on the current setting.

What command or graphical utility will do this?

Comment: Enabling the setting for creating Negative screen contrast may help you. Here is the link- https://askubuntu.com/questions/113031/how-do-i-change-screen-contrast/121209#121209

Comment: That is… not useful in my situation.

Comment: Sorry. There are 2 ways to adjust contrast 1) On the physical monitor settings 2) With the graphics card software settings. Here is a link with similar issue, hopefully it help:  http://superuser.com/questions/96539/how-do-i-adjust-display-contrast-and-brightness-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Videonauth This question is a year _older_.

Comment: and you hadn't had the chance to pick a correct answer for your problem to accept?

Comment: If a link to another answer on Ask Ubuntu contains the answer you would be better of flagging the question as a duplicate

Comment: Nothing had worked so far on that model. I don’t have regular access to the machine to check anymore.

Answer (score 48):

On command line (Terminal), try writing

```
xgamma -gamma 0.3
```

You should see a very noticeable difference. Experiment with different values. 1.0 is normal value. Setting a lower gamma will increase the contrast of bright values (decrease white washing), and setting a higher gamma will increase the contrast of dark values (but increase white washing).

Comment: Gamma is not contrast

Answer (score 21):

maybe you can try "xcalib".

```
sudo apt-get install xcalib
```

default(clear):

```
xcalib -c
```

Load ICC file:

```
xcalib ICC_file.icc
```

adjust contrast:

```
xcalib -co 70 -a
```

PS. number means percentage, -a means alter
if you want to adjust more, ask "man"! lol

```
man xcalib
```

hope that is helpful!!

Comment: Where are the icc profiles kept?

Comment: Ah, found some in `/usr/share/color/icc`.

Comment: Well, it does something, but it is not fixing the contrast issues.

Comment: This works only for current session. When I restart again it doesnot work

Comment: I installed xcalib and it seems to only decrease contrast: "xcalib -co 80 -a" decreased it, "xcalib -co 100 -a" left it unchanged, "xcalib -co 90 -a" decreased it some more... It seems multiplicative rather than on an absolute scale, but trying numbers >100 gives an error. Help? How can I get my original contrast back?

Comment: You can get the original contrast back by using `xcalib -c`. 
I got really spooked after the screen went grey on trying `xcalib -co 70 -a` :P

Answer (score 6):

I had no luck with `xgamma`, `compizconfig-settings-manager` or `xcalib`.

In the end, I was able to use `xrandr` to successfully change my screen's contrast (and other settings).

This was on an MSI laptop with an Nvidia Geforce GTX graphics card.

---

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

---

First run xrandr to see the available screens. `eDP-1-1` is the only connected screen in my case. Then run `xrandr --output <your screen> --gamma r:g:b`

See below for my terminal's output.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   ...
   ...
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  

$ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --gamma 0.8:0.8:0.8
```

Answer (score 5):

I have written a gui front-end for xcalib, which can be found on https://github.com/Ablinne/kolorcontrol.

It provides sliders for brightness/color and gamma for red/green and blue channels respectively. It will display the commands for an autostart script.