# How do I change screen contrast?

Tags: 11.10, laptop

The contrast on my laptop's screen is not enough for me.. Do you know how to change screen contrast in Ubuntu 11.10? I've tried xcalib and f.lux, but it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: What's are the manufacturer and model of you laptop? Did you look at its manual concerning this issue? Different models often use entirely different ways to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I adjust the screen contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91195/how-do-i-adjust-the-screen-contrast)

Comment: @Videonauth this question was asked when the only answer to "duplicate origin" was "xcalib" and here I explictily wrote I'm not interested in xcalib (but today I don't even remember why xcalib was wrong, I don't use Ubuntu anymore for many years).

Answer (score 1):

These instructions will allow you to invert the colors on your screen by pressing Ctrl+m. This should increase contrast and allow you to more easily see things when they are most difficult to read.

1. Install CompizConfigSettingsManager
2. Open it
3. Go under Accessibility
4. Check the box next to "Negative"
5. Click on "Negative" to open it's options
6. Change the "Toggle Screen Negative" key to Ctrl+m

Comment: The “negative“ effect doesn't change the image contrast. It negates the colour and brightness, which is something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

I have wondered why my Linux box had washed out colours compared to my windows gaming laptop. xgamma 0.7 solved that problem after half a year of wondering what question to write.