# How to get rid of washed out Colors and make them brighter in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics, color-management

My **current brightness is at 1.2 and the Gamma is set at 1.0**. I have tried a lot of combinations, but the Colors are either too bright or too washed out. I have also **set the RGB range to full**, but to no avail.

I have a **Lenovo Thinkpad with Intel HD 520 graphics with SKYLATE 2 driver.** Here are some screenshots of **what I want:**

[image: whatIwant_1]
[image: whatIwant_2]

Here are some screenshots of **what I am getting** on my primary screen:

[image: whatIhave_1]
[image: whatIhave_2]

So, you can see that the first set of images are brighter and Colors pop. However, the second set of pictures are dull, washed out, and unpleasant. What can I do more to fix this?

This is my first week using Ubuntu, and I have already exhausted everything from the internet. I used Xrandr to set a few attributes, such as brightness, broadcast RGB, max range, etc.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, it seems the screen contrast is too high, either you can check, the universal access https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-contrast.html.en or the Q&A of this https://askubuntu.com/questions/91195/how-do-i-adjust-the-screen-contrast may help.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Thank you for the advice. So, I checked out the question and set the contrast low, but everything turned too dark. Then I also viewed the documentation and turned on high contrast, and that didn’t help either. I have managed the Colors to some point, but as the pictures show that there is still noticeable dullness and white washing. Especially on videos. The videos play perfectly on other laptops and screens.

Comment: Instead of setting software brightness to **1.2** you should set it to **1.0** and adjust your hardware brightness up a bit. This might help too: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color.html.en

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Did that. Set the general brightness to 1.0, and hardware brightness to maximum. Now it looks dark. When I used windows 10, I rammed up the saturation and everything looked amazing and brighter. Here, I don’t have any saturation.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for but I'm not sure: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756082/how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I had already checked that answer yesterday. That is not the solution. Thank you though.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I have one TV with nvidia GTX 970M GPU and one TV (plus laptop) with Intel HD520 skylake and never had problems. I hope you find a solution soon.