# How to Permanently adjust Screen contrast Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, screen, contrast

I use `xgamma -gamma 0.7` but when I restart the computer I need to write that command again.

from this question [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91195/how-do-i-adjust-the-screen-contrast)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it "permanently", but you can redo the setting at every GUI login by putting a `.desktop` file in `$HOME/.config/autostart/`.

Look at examples in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`

Comment: Please be more specific for how I can adjust contrast @wal

Answer (score 0):

You can edit **$HOME/.bashrc** and add the line below.

`xgamma -gamma 0.7`

Then each time you login, the command is executed.

Comment: HI, I have edit the file, but when i login it still not change, but It change when I open Terminal it show this line then change contrast : -> Red  0.700, Green  0.700, Blue  0.700
<- Red  0.700, Green  0.700, Blue  0.700