# Can I adjust my brightness for Amazon videos

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-mate

I am running Ubuntu-Mate 22.04.

I play Amazon videos and often the light level is low.

I did a search but could not find any thing helpful.

Is there a way that I can make those light levels higher?

Comment: What is the distinction between the light level in the Amazon video and your whole system? Is increasing your screen brightness on your monitor or through your laptop function buttons enough? Or do you want something like https://askubuntu.com/a/694984/1004020 ? The live video enhancement stuff from Windows isn't widespread on Linux, and if you still want that, you can try messing with adding ReShade to your browser

Comment: @Daniel T I do not need my light level increased for my whole system. I do not run Windows, so it does not apply.

Comment: Are you watching Amazon videos on https://www.primevideo.com/ ? If you are able to watch there, I could try writing a userscript for you

Comment: You could just increase the gamma of your display. If you use an Nvidia card there is an easy command for this. Probably for other systems too.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The gamma solution was exactly what the top answer in the question I linked suggested. Unfortunately the asker does not seem to want to change anything in the system outside of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are watching Amazon videos in a browser at https://www.primevideo.com/ . Amazons says that option is available for all platforms.

If it's an app instead, it would be more difficult to modify the brightness. Any special video effects that Windows might have are bundled with the graphics driver. That is not generally available on Windows, and injecting stuff there is difficult.

Here, I will use the simple solution of injecting a stylesheet to apply a filter effect on the `<video>` element. This is easier and less invasive than trying to enhance the video through the Ubuntu system.

## New simpler solution

1. Click on https://userstyles.world/style/14430/increase-video-brightness
2. Click on the cyan "Get Stylus" button. It is a privacy-respecting alternative to Stylish. If only the blue install button appears, skip to step 4
3. Search for and click on either the Chrome or Firefox links
4. Click on the blue "install button"
5. Click on "Install style"
6. Click on "Edit" if desired
7. Click on "Save" after you finish editing
8. Open your Amazon video. If it's not primevideo.com, then edit the domain.

## Old solution

1. Install TamperMonkey in Firefox.
2. Create a new userscript and paste this into it

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Amazon videos brightness
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2024-01-29
// @description  Increases amazon video brightness
// @author       https://github.com/danielzgtg
// @match        https://www.primevideo.com/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    /*
     * Change the @match above to whatever website your Amazon videos are at.
     * Freely change the values inside the contrast and brightness below
     * to what you prefer.
     */
    GM_addStyle(`video {
    filter:
        contrast(110%)
        brightness(110%)
        !important; }`);
})();
```

3. Save
4. Open a new tab to your Amazon video

Comment: I installed TamperMonkey. How do I install the userscript?

Comment: 1. Click on the TamperMonkey icon (click on the extensions puzzle piece icon if it's not there) 2. Click on "Dashboard" 3. Click on the "[+]" tab

Comment: There is no dashboard.

Comment: @fixit7 I added screenshots for every step

Comment: As my previous post, I have NO dashboard.

Comment: @fixit7 Ok, I replaced the userscript with a simpler, clickable userstyle solution that uses the safer Stylus extension